# Guaranteeing a FK relationship through multiple tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm using MySQL / InnoDB, and using foreign keys to preserve relationships across tables. In the following scenaro (depicted below), a 'manager' is associated with a 'recordLabel', and an 'artist' is also associated with a 'recordLabel'. When an 'album' is created, it is associated with an 'artist' and a 'manager', but both the artist and the manager need to be associated with the **same** recordLabel. How can I guarantee that relationship with the current table setup, or do I need to redesign the tables?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this result using pure DRI - Declarative Referential Integrity, or the linking of foreign keys to ensure the schema's referential integrity.

There are 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. Consider the requirement a database problem, and use a [trigger on INSERT and UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) to validate the requirements, and fail otherwise.
2. Consider the nested link a business logic requirement, and implement it in your business logic in PHP/C#/whatever.

As a sidenote, I think the structure is rather strange from a practical perspective - as far as I know an `Artist` is signed to a `RecordLabel`, and assigned a `Manager` separately (either from the label or individually, many artists retain their own manager when switching to another label). Linking the `Manager` also to the `Album` only makes sense to record historic managers, enabling you to retrieve who was the manager to the artist when the album was released, but that automatically means your requirement is invalid if the artist switches labels and/or manages later on. I think therefore it is wrong from a practical data view to enforce this link.

Comment: Thanks.. The relationship between the four entities was purely to illustrate the problem (which has nothing to do with the recording industry), but I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'd recommend using just A, B, C and D for entities if the example must be 'obscured', saves a lot of practical comments like my sidenote hehe. Apart from that, the first half of the answer is still valid for all 'diamond' relationships like this.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is add recordLabel id to the albums table.  Then you put two, two column indexes on albumns (recordLabel_id, artist_id) and (recordLabel_id, managers_id).

Because the record_id can only have one value in each row of the albumns table you will have insured integrity.

Comment: Denormalizing data to achieve refential integrity seems a rather strange concept.

Comment: I think you could say there is an inherent relationship that needs to be defined between the albums and recordLabels.  If each albumn be definition belong to only one recordLabel then I am ok with it.